# clean reinstall of Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting several errors every time I open Visual Studio, including but not limited to:

> "The GitCollaborationPackage package did not load correctly"
>
> "The FileIndicatorPackage package did not load correctly"
>
> "The NuGetPackage package did not load correctly"

and finally:

> "An error occurred that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x80040154). If the problem persists, repair your Visual Studio installation via 'Add or Remove Programs' in Control Panel."

How can I just remove Visual Studio and start over? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times. Thanks!

Comment: A factory reset of the machine (reinstall Windows) typically resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I proved that a reset of the operating system followed by a re-install of VO2015 fixes the problem, but in doing so there was MUCH more grief reinstalling all the software and finding licence numbers. In some cases because I did not uninstall certain programs first, they ran out of activations once they were re-installed. It all became too much and so I reverted back to an image backup I had taken before the Reset.

I too am looking now at a way to uninstall VO2015 cleanly so that a re-install will work correctly (I tried it again after the image recall, but still obtained the errors.) I think that the install file for VO2015 is very unfriendly - it stops when files are found that are already installed (e.g. C++ libraries and Nu-Get libraries). Why it does not continue when it finds them installed is beyond me!